# How to dont allow registered users to comment without being logged in?

Tags: comments, registered

Currently, if users have a registration on website they can post their comments without login too, only using their email address. In this way registered users' avatar will be shown on the site. If any (anonym, not-registered) users know their email address they can post comments like a registered users' (or admin) using their avatar.

Is there any way to dont allow registered users to post comments without being logged in? Error attention? or any way?

On my site registered and unregistered users can be able to post comment. There is no way to hold all comments for moderation, or required registration for all users. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but... I think there's an option that does exactly what you need...

If you log in as Administrator and go to Settings->Discussion you should see this option "Users must be registered and logged in to comment".

[image]

Comment: hy, thx but is not good way for me. If this checked users can post comment only after registration.

I would like to allow the comments for all users. So I need a solution like this:

"Registered users must logged in to comment." and 

"Unregistered users can comment without being logged in."

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: So I need a solution like this: "Registered users must logged in to comment." and "Unregistered users can comment without being logged in." If the users have registration they must be logged in, if not they can post comment.

Comment: And how do you want to check if user is registered when he's not logged in?

Comment: This is the issue. Im not a programmer. Maybe a any function? Eg.: if (is_user_"have registration"()) { Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @laca123 It's not an issue for programmer. If user is not logged in then he's anonymous. It's impossible for site to guess if he's registered user or not... So there is no such function like `is_user_"have_registration"` because there is no user, if current visit is generated by someone who's not logged in... Of course you can check if email address used in comment is already taken by one of registered users, but... I can put anything as e-mail address, when I'm writing a comment...

Comment: thx for your help. This is my problem you've written. I'm admin in my site. I have own avatar with my face. If you know my (or any registered users) email address, and you as unregistered user put my mail when youre writing the comment, my face will be shown! But the comment wasn't taken by me, admin or registered user. So, spam bot or any user can take a comment -> abusing my (or registered users) face or name... I can not decide that comment was taken by registered user or any user, or spam bot. There is GDPR :)

Comment: Ahhh, I see your problem now. Yes, you can solve it. Let me fiddle with some code a little bit and I'll update my answer later on.